# 500 Internal Server Error when logging into Magento front end?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

This used to work fine but we've just moved the site from the development area to httpdocs. I've changed all relevant MySQL entries and file paths, but still we're having this error.

In the Apache error log, This is the corresponding error:

> client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/var/www/vhosts...

It looks like it is getting the wrong path somehow, as the /var/www/vhosts is repeating.

I did try using powergrep to locate where the path is getting set, but it didn't return any results.

Is there a setting which I can specify the exact path?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check your PHP log, it will give you a detailed info about this error.

Have you checked your permissions? 
The folders var and media must be writtable.

And also, could you see correctly the homepage, categories and the error only appears when you log in?

Best regards.

Comment: I got this working in the end by just reverting to an old backup. No idea what caused it.